# Pine Script - Buy/Sell indicator for TradingView with various conditions

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm sure what I'm trying to do isn't complex at all but looking for help. Everything is good so far with the script but, I don't know how to add an additional condition to a buy signal. I have it set to give me a buy signal for each white candle but, I want it to only give the buy signal for the first white candle after a red/pink candle. (Not all white candles) just the first one after a red/pink candle close. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR2YZ.png)

```
////@version=4
study(title="EMA Candles Buy Signals", shorttitle="EMA Buy Signals", overlay=true)

////INPUTS////
src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
fast = input(5) //Fast EMA Band
slow = input(26) //Slow EMA Band

////EMA FORMULAS////
fe = ema(src, fast)
se = ema(src, slow)

////OH92's FAVORITE COLORS////
g = #8cffe5
r = #ff848a
gg = #adff75
rr = #ff80be
w = #ffffff

////BAR COLOR FORMULA////
bc = fe > se ? (crossunder(src, se) ? w : src > fe ? g : src > se ? gg : w) : (crossover(src, se) ? w : src < fe ? r : src < se ? rr : src > fe ? src > se ? gg : na : na)

///GENERATE BUY SIGNALS BASED ON w COLOR///
buySignal = bc == w

///PLOT BUY SIGNALS///
plotshape(series=buySignal, title="Buy Signal", location=location.belowbar, color=#ffffff, style=shape.labelup, text="Buy")

///OUTPUT///
barcolor(bc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your condition was not `true` on the previous bar and is `true` on the current bar.

```
is_new_buy = not buySignal[1] and buySignal
```

Then use this variable to trigger your label.

```
plotshape(series=is_new_buy, title="Buy Signal", location=location.belowbar, color=#ffffff, style=shape.labelup, text="Buy")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess Im still not understanding the first part. How would you write the code (is_new_buy = not buySignal[1] and buySignal) for the previous bar color?

Comment: `buySignal` is the variable that is used in the `plotshape()` condition. It is also linked to white bar color with `buySignal = bc == w`, `w` here is the white color.

Comment: I guess I'm just not understanding, what helps me understand the best is seeing what the code needs to look like with the conditions I'm trying to input.